# Handshake failed with fatal error SSL_ERROR_SSL: error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed

Tags: ssl-certificate, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am stuck with this error while trying to create a channel using api (I am using a similar sample to balance transfer example from fabric samples)

However,I can create a channel,install,instantiate and invoke using the cli commands

I have enclosed both the screenshot of the error and my network-config file[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Jprz.png)

> ### --networkconfig.yaml--
>
> #
>
> ## The network connection profile provides client applications the information about the target
>
> ## blockchain network that are necessary for the applications to interact with it. These are all
>
> ## knowledge that must be acquired from out-of-band sources. This file provides such a source.
>
> ## name: "business-connect"
>
> #
>
> ## Any properties with an "x-" prefix will be treated as application-specific, exactly like how naming
>
> ## in HTTP headers or swagger properties work. The SDK will simply ignore these fields and leave
>
> ## them for the applications to process. This is a mechanism for different components of an application
>
> ## to exchange information that are not part of the standard schema described below. In particular,
>
> ## the "x-type" property with the "hlfv1" value example below is used by Hyperledger Composer to
>
> ## determine the type of Fabric networks (v0.6 vs. v1.0) it needs to work with.
>
> ## x-type: "hlfv1"
>
> #
>
> ## Describe what the target network is/does.
>
> ## description: "Business connect-POC"
>
> #
>
> ## Schema version of the content. Used by the SDK to apply the corresponding parsing rules.
>
> ## version: "1.0"
>
> #
>
> ## The client section will be added on a per org basis see org1.yaml and org2.yaml
>
> #
>
> ## client:
>
> #
>
> ## [Optional]. But most apps would have this section so that channel objects can be constructed
>
> ## based on the content below. If an app is creating channels, then it likely will not need this
>
> ## section.
>
> ## channels:   # name of the channel   internal-channel:
>
> ```
> # Required. list of orderers designated by the application to use for transactions on this
> # channel. This list can be a result of access control ("org1" can only access "ordererA"), or
> # operational decisions to share loads from applications among the orderers.  The values must
> # be "names" of orgs defined under "organizations/peers"
> orderers:
>   - orderer1-htc
>
> # Required. list of peers from participating orgs
> peers:
>   peer1-accounts:
>     # [Optional]. will this peer be sent transaction proposals for endorsement? The peer must
>     # have the chaincode installed. The app can also use this property to decide which peers
>     # to send the chaincode install request. Default: true
>     endorsingPeer: true
>
>     # [Optional]. will this peer be sent query proposals? The peer must have the chaincode
>     # installed. The app can also use this property to decide which peers to send the
>     # chaincode install request. Default: true
>     chaincodeQuery: true
>
>     # [Optional]. will this peer be sent query proposals that do not require chaincodes, like
>     # queryBlock(), queryTransaction(), etc. Default: true
>     ledgerQuery: true
>
>     # [Optional]. will this peer be the target of the SDK's listener registration? All peers can
>     # produce events but the app typically only needs to connect to one to listen to events.
>     # Default: true
>     eventSource: true
>
>   peer1-mgmt:
>     endorsingPeer: false
>     chaincodeQuery: true
>     ledgerQuery: true
>     eventSource: false
>
>   peer1-project:
>     endorsingPeer: false
>     chaincodeQuery: true
>     ledgerQuery: true
>     eventSource: true
>
>
> # [Optional]. what chaincodes are expected to exist on this channel? The application can use
> # this information to validate that the target peers are in the expected state by comparing
> # this list with the query results of getInstalledChaincodes() and getInstantiatedChaincodes()
> chaincodes:
>   # the format follows the "cannonical name" of chaincodes by fabric code
>   - mycontract-v0.1
> ```
>
> #
>
> ## list of participating organizations in this network
>
> ## organizations:   htc:
>
> ```
> mspid: htcMSP
> orderer: 
>   - orderer1-htc
> certificateAuthorities:
>   - ica-htc   accounts:
> mspid: accountsMSP
>
> peers:
>   - peer1-accounts
>
> # [Optional]. Certificate Authorities issue certificates for identification purposes in a Fabric based
> # network. Typically certificates provisioning is done in a separate process outside of the
> # runtime network. Fabric-CA is a special certificate authority that provides a REST APIs for
> # dynamic certificate management (enroll, revoke, re-enroll). The following section is only for
> # Fabric-CA servers.
> certificateAuthorities:
>   - ica-accounts
>
> # [Optional]. If the application is going to make requests that are reserved to organization
> # administrators, including creating/updating channels, installing/instantiating chaincodes, it
> # must have access to the admin identity represented by the private key and signing certificate.
> # Both properties can be the PEM string or local path to the PEM file. Note that this is mainly for
> # convenience in development mode, production systems should not expose sensitive information
> # this way. The SDK should allow applications to set the org admin identity via APIs, and only use
> # this route as an alternative when it exists.
> adminPrivateKey:
>   path: network/data/orgs/accounts/admin/msp/keystore/accounts_sk
> signedCert:
>   path: network/data/orgs/accounts/admin/msp/signcerts/cert.pem
> ```
>
> # the profile will contain public information about organizations
>   other than the one it belongs to.   # These are necessary information
>   to make transaction lifecycles work, including MSP IDs and   # peers
>   with a public URL to send transaction proposals. The file will not
>   contain private   # information reserved for members of the
>   organization, such as admin key and certificate,   # fabric-ca
>   registrar enroll ID and secret, etc.   mgmt:
>       mspid: mgmtMSP
>       peers:
>         - peer1-mgmt
>       certificateAuthorities:
>         - ica-mgmt
>       adminPrivateKey:
>         path: network/data/orgs/mgmt/admin/msp/keystore/mgmt_sk
>       signedCert:
>         path: network/data/orgs/mgmt/admin/msp/signcerts/cert.pem   project:
>       mspid: projectMSP
>       peers:
>         - peer1-project
>       certificateAuthorities:
>         - ica-project
>       adminPrivateKey:
>         path: network/data/orgs/project/admin/msp/keystore/project_sk
>       signedCert:
>         path: network/data/orgs/project/admin/msp/signcerts/cert.pem
>
> #
>
> ## List of orderers to send transaction and channel create/update requests to. For the time
>
> ## being only one orderer is needed. If more than one is defined, which one get used by the
>
> ## SDK is implementation specific. Consult each SDK's documentation for its handling of orderers.
>
> ## orderers:   orderer1-htc:
>
> ```
> url: grpcs://localhost:7050
>
> # these are standard properties defined by the gRPC library
> # they will be passed in as-is to gRPC client constructor
> grpcOptions:
>   ssl-target-name-override: orderer1-htc
> tlsCACerts:
>   path: network/data/htc.crt
> ```
>
> #
>
> ## List of peers to send various requests to, including endorsement, query
>
> ## and event listener registration.
>
> ## peers:   peer1-accounts:
>
> ```
> # this URL is used to send endorsement and query requests
> url: grpcs://localhost:7051
> grpcOptions:
>   ssl-target-name-override: peer1-accounts
> tlsCACerts:
>   path: network/data/accounts.crt
> ```
>
> peer1-mgmt:
>       url: grpcs://localhost:8051
>       grpcOptions:
>         ssl-target-name-override: peer1-mgmt
>       tlsCACerts:
>         path: network/data/mgmt.crt
>
> peer1-project:
>       url: grpcs://localhost:9051
>
> ```
> grpcOptions:
>   ssl-target-name-override: peer1-project
> tlsCACerts:
>   path: network/data/project.crt
> ```
>
> #
>
> ## Fabric-CA is a special kind of Certificate Authority provided by Hyperledger Fabric which allows
>
> ## certificate management to be done via REST APIs. Application may choose to use a standard
>
> ## Certificate Authority instead of Fabric-CA, in which case this section would not be specified.
>
> ## certificateAuthorities:   ica-htc:
>
> ```
> url: http://localhost:1054
> httpOptions:
>   verify: false
> tlsCACerts:
>   path: network/data/htc-ca-cert.pem
> registrar:
>   - enrollId: ica-htc-admin
>     enrollSecret: ica-htc-adminpw
> # [Optional] The optional name of the CA.
> caName: ica-htc   ica-accounts:
> url: http://localhost:7054
> # the properties specified under this object are passed to the 'http' client verbatim when
> # making the request to the Fabric-CA server
> httpOptions:
>   verify: false
> tlsCACerts:
>   path: network/data/accounts-ca-chain.pem
>
> # Fabric-CA supports dynamic user enrollment via REST APIs. A "root" user, a.k.a registrar, is
> # needed to enroll and invoke new users.
> registrar:
>   - enrollId: ica-accounts-admin
>     enrollSecret: ica-accounts-adminpw
> # [Optional] The optional name of the CA.
> caName: ica-accounts
> ```
>
> ica-mgmt:
>       url: http://localhost:8054
>       httpOptions:
>         verify: false
>       tlsCACerts:
>         path: network/data/mgmt-ca-chain.pem
>       registrar:
>         - enrollId: ica-mgmt-admin
>           enrollSecret: ica-mgmt-adminpw
>       # [Optional] The optional name of the CA.
>       caName: ica-mgmt
>
> ica-project:
>       url: http://localhost:9054
>       httpOptions:
>         verify: false
>       tlsCACerts:
>         path: network/data/project-ca-chain.pem
>       registrar:
>         - enrollId: ica-project-admin
>           enrollSecret: ica-project-adminpw
>       # [Optional] The optional name of the CA.
>       caName: ica-project

Comment: Handshake errors usually occur when the communication protocols don't match on the client and server side. Double check that if your network configuration file uses grpcs:// and https:// protocols, then your Fabric network is also configured for TLS (and viceversa).

Comment: Another reason could be your version of Node is unsupported (compatibility problem with grpc on nodejs.). The docs say it should be 8.9.x (at time of writing for Fabric 1.4) https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/prereqs.html

Comment: hi @paul O'Mahony I am using v8.15.0 and i can able to execute almost all the api call in balance-transfer example and my network is configured with tls and my network configuration file uses grpcs and https protocols

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are getting a hostname verification error on the TLS handshake. In your settings

```
# this URL is used to send endorsement and query requests
url: grpcs://localhost:7051
grpcOptions:
  ssl-target-name-override: peer1-accounts
tlsCACerts:
  path: network/data/accounts.crt
```

you are calling `localhost` but you set the override to `peer1-accounts`.  The hostname you use in the URL must match one of the SANs in the TLS certificate used by the peer OR whatever value you set for `ssl-target-name-override` must match one of the SANs in the TLS certificate.

You can print the details of the certificate using openssl:

`openssl x509 -noout -text -in path-to-tls-cert`

Answer (score 0):

This problem is related to blocks in the Firewall. When I disabled SSL checking on my firewall, it worked again, no problem